# Why there are logback log files with .1 .2 .3 extensions?

Tags: java, logging, logback

There are log files with .1 .2 .3 etc extensions in an application log folder and I don't know why. There is also the log file with correct name but it is empty. For example:

```
app.log             │      0│Sep 14 02:12 <---
app.log.1           │116350K│Sep 14 10:45 <---
app.log.2016-09-10.1│102403K│Sep 10 18:39
app.log.2016-09-10.2│ 90241K│Sep 11 01:59
app.log.2016-09-11.0│      0│Sep 11 23:36
app.log.2016-09-12.0│102401K│Sep 12 04:54
app.log.2016-09-12.1│102401K│Sep 12 06:13
app.log.2016-09-12.2│102401K│Sep 12 07:13
app.log.2016-09-13.0│102403K│Sep 14 02:12
app.log.2016-09-13.1│102401K│Sep 13 19:49
app.log.2016-09-13.2│ 75914K│Sep 14 01:59
```

This happens occasionally without any apparent reason.

The logback.xml is below:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="15 seconds">
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${log_file}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log_file}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{ISO8601}|%-25.25t|%-5.5p|%-60.60c|%m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Edit: the first log line in app.log.1 has the timestamp `2016-09-14 00:00:00,003`

Edit: According to @Kiskae suggestion I modified the logback.xml to comply the documentation and updated the version of logback from 1.1.3 to 1.1.7. However it didn't help. Here is the new logback.xml

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="15 seconds">
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${log_file}</file>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log_file}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>200GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>%d{ISO8601}|%-25.25t|%-5.5p|%-60.60c|%m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>

</appender>


<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<fileNamePattern>${log_file}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i</fileNamePattern>` - This specifies the filename pattern, since you used a `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` rollingPolicy it will create a new log file every day. The `%i` token represents an increasing integer that will be used to open a new file if a log reaches the configured `maxFileSize`:

> Note the "%i" conversion token in addition to "%d". Both the %i and %d tokens are mandatory. Each time the current log file reaches maxFileSize before the current time period ends, it will be archived with an increasing index, starting at 0.

Source: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy

Comment: I don't think you answered my question. As you can see from the original post, `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` works most of the times correctly as it creates files like `app.log.2016-09-12.0` and `app.log.2016-09-12.1`, etc. However it happens sometime, that a file `app.log.1` is created and the log is redirected into it and the regular log file `app.log` stays empty. Can you please point me into the part of the documentation which explains this behavior?

Comment: @miloxe The only thing that jumps out is that your definition mixes 3 different appenders in a way not specified in the docs. Perhaps going through the docs and rebuilding the file will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Kiskae. I have followed your advice and rebuilt the appender according to the documentation. I also have updated the logback version from 1.1.3 to 1.1.7. I will be checking the log file for next few days if it is working as it has to.

Comment: Unfortunately the changes I've made according the documentation haven't helped to resolve the issue. After the weekend there is the file `app.log.1` in the application log folder.

Comment: @miloxe The only other thing that comes to mind is that something is preventing access to the original `app.log`. Perhaps a secondary application, quirks in the file system or permission issues?

Comment: Thanks for the effort again, @Kiskae. I suppose that could be the case, but I was not able to find the cause yet. As soon as I will find it, I will post an update. The issue is happening on our dev server, on the production server is everything OK.